# Rogue Java process brings my computer to a halt

Tags: process, java, kill, proc

In reference to my earlier post: [Is there a log of past threads that are now closed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25225/is-there-a-log-of-past-threads-that-are-now-closed)

I gave the process a `kill -STOP` signal and started examining the details. I can't seem to figure out why it is acting up. The problem lies with IcedTea, which is (from what I understand) something to do with Java applets on the web. Below is the contents of `/proc/13784/cmdline`:

```
 /usr/lib64/jvm/jre//bin/java
-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/netx.jar:/usr/share/icedtea-web/plugin.jar:/usr/share/java/js.jar
-classpath
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre//lib/rt.jar
sun.applet.PluginMain
/tmp/icedteaplugin-max/13636-icedteanp-plugin-to-appletviewer
/tmp/icedteaplugin-max/13636-icedteanp-appletviewer-to-plugin
```

I've never poked around the `/proc` directories. Which file would be the most telling of my issue here? This process uses 90%+ of my processor speed and brings my core temperature to 75C (sometimes causing a shutdown).

**EDIT** This process uses 170%+ of my CPU according to `htop`

Comment: The `cmdline` pseudo-file is null-separated. Null bytes don't show up in the terminal. Try instead `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/13647/cmdline` so the arguments appear on separate lines.