# Script error handling: need to report segfault in script run by ssh

Tags: ssh, signals, error-handling

I wrote a `cron` job, which uses `ssh` to run a script on a server.  I just tried running the script, and now I am unhappy.

```
client# ssh server.local /usr/local/bin/script
client#

server# /usr/local/bin/script
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
server#

client# ssh server.local /usr/local/bin/script
client# echo $?
255
```

I can confirm the crash is in the script interpreter, `/bin/sh` (a symlink to `/bin/dash`).  For example, when I ran `script &` on the server, the shell tells me the background job has PID 30860, and that is the next PID that shows up in the list of crashes in `coredumpctl`.  I will need to solve the crash, but this question is only about how to detect such crashes.

`cron` supports error reporting by "sending mail" when a job prints any message.  But it [does not mail on non-zero exit status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27542/29483).  So my current cron job would not mail me about this error.  (And if it did, I would really like to have a more helpful pointer for troubleshooting than "Exited with code 255").

`cron` is relying on the Unix convention, that "no news is good news".  But that convention is being broken here.

I interpret this as a limitation of SSH.  If I wanted to always notice segmentation faults in remote commands, what rule could I follow, to work around this SSH limitation?

(I'm also interested if there's a "good reason" for this limitation.  I think I know more-or-less *how* it could happen, at the implementation level).

Comment: Hmmm... What is it that prints the `Segmentation fault` string to the terminal? Is it the shell that runs the command, or is it printed by the thing that has the fault?

Comment: @Kusalananda edited. I have confirmed a segfault occurs in the binary interpreter of `script`.  Then "Segmentation fault" is almost certainly printed by the main shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
% cat segfault.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *s = "hello world";
    *s = 'H';
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
% CFLAGS=-g make segfault
gcc -g    segfault.c   -o segfault
```

The error comes from something performing some `waitpid` call, typically the shell:

```
% ./segfault
zsh: bus error  ./segfault
```

as here `zsh` has dropped out of a `waitpid` and then wandered through some code path involving `WIFSIGNALED`. (macOS issues a bus error instead of segfault (a rose by any other name) and the exact string error will vary depending on shell.)

OpenSSH portable (as of commit ed7bd5d93fe14c7bd90febd29b858ea985d14d45) does make various `WIFSIGNALED(status)` calls notably in `misc.c`, `session.c`, and `sshd.c`; some of these `return -1` which could easily turn into the observed `255` exit status, though I'd need to add debugging or trace `sshd` to see exactly how this case happens (`ssh -v -v -v` does not help, nor do the default `sshd` logs).

As a kluge, you can force a `waitpid` to happen. This requires tricking a shell into not performing a simple `exec` to replace itself which it will do as an optimization if it can:

```
% ssh localhost 'sh -c ./segfault'
% ssh localhost ':; ./segfault'
% ssh localhost 'sh -c ":; ./segfault"'
sh: line 1:  9068 Bus error: 10           ./segfault
%
```

`:; ...` is complex enough that `sh` does not `fork`/`exec` and instead ends up `waitpid` on `segfault` and then does report on that. Note that error reporting will vary depending on the exact flavor of `sh`.

```
% ssh localhost '/usr/local/bin/sh -c ":; ./segfault"'
Bus Error
```

Now, if `sh` itself is causing the segfault (or whatever unexpected signal) you will need to inspect the exit code of SSH. Another option would be to call a small wrapper that does the `waitpid` without shell tricks:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>    
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: waiter command [args ..]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        err(1, "could not fork");
    } else if (pid == 0) {      /* child */
        argv++;
        execvp(*argv, argv);
        err(1, "could not exec");
    } else {                    /* parent */
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
            err(1, "could not waitpid");
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            exit(WEXITSTATUS(status));
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            warnx("child exited with signal %d", WTERMSIG(status));
            exit(128 + WTERMSIG(status));
        } else {
            err(1, "unknown waitpid condition?? status=%d", status);
        }
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

... though this wrapper *also* could segfault (or whatever signal) especially if the server has hardware problems, bad memory, etc.

```
% ssh localhost ./waiter ./segfault
waiter: child exited with signal 10
```

However the wrapper has much less code than a typical `sh` (~50 lines versus ~10,000 for the heirloom bourne shell) so should be less likely to itself cause an exit-by-signal condition. (You did check that exit code, right?)

Comment: It turned out my problem was a `dash` segfault triggered by some sort of buggy script with infinite recursion.  But, a bus error could also occur due to I/O error when demand-paging a binary executable. I was hoping to be able to catch that. I don't think I can use a wrapper to detect a bus error inside the wrapper itself. Seems I need to start with a rule like "openssh cannot be trusted to print an error, you must check its exit status and print a error yourself". To be fair, when I can see the error, it is a fairly clear second step to start testing from an interactive shell on the server.

Comment: a small wrapper would be a lot simpler than even a `sh` shell though yes it could itself fall over and die if something is horribly awry on a server