# How can I keep track of what's using the most CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu, top, nagios

I use `nagios` to monitor my server. Once in a while I'll get a report that the CPU load is warning / critical, etc. Usually this happens at some odd hour or when I don't have the tools to immediately log in and look around.

Is there some way that I can set up the system to take some `top` snapshots when the CPU usage is very high - either independently on the system or via `nagios`?

Answer (score 2):

Process accounting (package psacct) can also help.

Comment: Read this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25225/is-there-a-log-of-past-threads-that-are-now-closed

Comment: @Alien Life Form - +1 but a little more elaboration would be nice

Answer (score 1):

You could run `ps aux >> logfile` every minute with `cron`. It includes CPU usage.

Comment: That's not bad. But really I only would like to log this when the CPU usage is above a certain threshold. Is there a way to "trigger" it? Or perhaps only store it to a file when it is above a certain point?

Comment: Also it would be nice to have a way to order processes by highest CPU usage.

Comment: ps aux |sort -n -k 3

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at snmpd (snmpd.conf). If compiled with the right options you can set trigger actions for a number of things - one of these is CPU-load.

Comment: cool, i like the looks of this. i found the "load average checks" section of the config file - i hope that means it was compiled right on my system. i've been trying to google for instruction on how to "set it up" to give me alerts. what should i be googling for?