# User's executed commands log file

Tags: logs, monitoring, command-history

In Unix based systems, is there a `log file` that stores user's executed command(s)?

Comment: Are you asking on a per user basis or system-wide logging of user commands?

Comment: I want all users commands logging, i have root access to system.

Comment: See also [Log every invocation of every SUID program?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13017) [Is there a log of past threads that are now closed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25225) You may get better answers if you say what you're after: accounting CPU time? Watching for intrusion attempts? Analyzing a break-in post mortem? …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you want to track all user commands, you should look at the `acct` package on your system (on some systems this is also called "process accounting" or `psacct`).  Then after it's been turned on, you can run the `lastcomm` command to show what programs have been run, by whom, when and for how long.  From Google, search "linux acct" for more details.

http://beginlinux.com/blog/2010/01/monitoring-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html

Comment: Note that process accounting only logs the command name, which can be forged easily (copy or symlink the executable to the name of your choice).

Comment: and only logging the command name without its arguments is kind of useless.