# How to track the number of processes and forks per user?

Tags: linux, centos, process, logs, fork

I need to figure out  how many forks are done and how many concurrent processes are run by each user over time. It does not look like this information is tracked by my distribution.

I know how to sets limits, but I'm interested in tracking these numbers for each user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `psacct` package (GNU accounting), it should do just about everything you need, once installed and enabled (`accton`), then `lastcomm` will keep report on user processes (see also `sa` and `dump-acct`). See this for reference: [User's executed commands log file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32740/users-executed-commands-log-file/32744#32744)

You might need to upgrade the version to log PID/PPID, see https://serverfault.com/questions/334547/how-can-i-enable-pid-and-ppid-fields-in-psacct-dump-acct , otherwise I suspect it will under-report on `fork()` without `exec()`.

**Update**
If your `lastcomm` outputs `F` in the 2nd column it means the process was a fork (that never called `exec()` to replace itself with a new process). The output of `dump-acct` *should* show you the PID (and PPID) in acct v3 format.

An alternative to psacct might be the new(ish) `taskstats`, there's not a huge amount of support for it yet AFAICT, see `Documentation/accounting/taskstats.txt` in your kernel version source. This might help get you started <strike>http://code.google.com/p/arsenalsuite/wiki/TrackingIOUsage</strike> https://code.google.com/archive/p/anim-studio-tools/  The specific code example is `tasklogger.c`, you will need to modify the `printf()` line in function `print_delayacct2()`, firstly to replace `%u` with `%llu` for the `__u64` types and secondly to add the field `ac_uid` (and perhaps `ac_gid`) that you need to track by user. Invoke it with something like `tasklogger -dl -m 0-1` (where `-m 0-1` indicates CPUs 0-1). You will then see realtime details as each process exits.

There is also a perl module [`Linux::Taskstats::Read`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Linux-Taskstats-Read/lib/Linux/Taskstats/Read.pm) available on CPAN, though I have not used it.

You'll need to process the data based on timestamps if you want the *concurrent* process count per-user, this is not a simple as it sounds.

**Update 2**
Ok, the things to check for the required `psacct` support are:

1. (official) kernel >= 2.6.8 for v3 accounting support (or backport)
2. kernel with `CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT` and `CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT_V3` enabled
3. v3 capable accounting (`psacct`) package, as noted above

All of the above *should* be true in CentOS 6, I've checked a 5.x and it *does not* have `CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACCT_V3=y`, so you would have to rebuild your kernel to enable it.

The original `psacct-6.3.2` is about 15 years old, the Red Hat/CentOS version has backported v3 and PID display support (I can't test it right now, but it should work).

To check a your kernel config:

```
zgrep BSD_PROCESS_ACCT /proc/config.gz /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Process accounting only tracks execs, not forks.

Comment: @Gilles, mine does (psacct-6.4pre1, kernel 2.6.31.6, Slackware 13).  Tested with code that calls `fork()`, and using bash `( ... )` subshells. Answer updated to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps -ef` to look at the child pid, the parent id is the one that did the forking or spawning.  You could use `watch` to run a script on a regular basis and do the counting for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to log forks (and whatever other system call catches your fancy).

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S clone
```