# how to record all who that login to my linux machines and records them

Tags: linux, security, login, command-history

I installed the package audit on my linux red-hat 6.x machine
in order to view the recored of each user that log to my linux machine

```
yum install audit
```

kit installation from: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-installing_the_audit_packages.html

after installation and restart the audit service as

```
service auditd start
```

I follow the audir.log file 
in order to see the users records

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

but from this log I see only the User IP's and when he login to my linux machine

the records of the linux command that user perfromed not apperars in the **audit.log**

can some one advice why we not see the history of linux command in **audit.log**?

example of **audit.log**

```
type=USER_START msg=audit(1422876162.936:152): user pid=28114 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35        addr=10.1.113.35 terminal=ssh res=s'
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1422876162.940:153): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0            ses=74236 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35            addr=10.1.113.35     terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1422876162.940:154): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35 addr=10.1.113.35 terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1422876162.940:155): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=99:c8:56:79:64:17:0b:67:b5:6c:e9:36:22:8a:b1:88 direction=? spid=28116 suid=0 '
type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1422876162.940:156): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=6f:b9:bf:4f:84:1f:58:e5:d2:1c:94:1f:11:8e:26:61 direction=? spid=28116 suid=0 '
type=CRED_REFR msg=audit(1422876162.940:157): user pid=28116 uid=0 auid=0 ses=74236 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.1.113.35 addr=10.1.113.35 terminal=ssh res=success'
```

- remark in case this tool Audit can't do the records of each user , please help me to find other tool that can do the Job

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it takes more effort than using some external tools, but `last` or `utmpdump` supply all the needed remote login info using those files (read http://xmodulo.com/monitor-user-login-history-centos-utmpdump.html for more info about those files):

```
/var/log/wtmp  
/var/log/btmp
/var/run/utmp
```

and as it was said above you can handle the user-shell-command-history recording on your own.

Comment: the link not explain how to view what user type on linux machine ( history )

Comment: No it only explains about the login recordings without any external tool. To trace user commands, you should use user's shell history files. The other answer links describes how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the login data alredy available in `auth.log` without additional packages?

`command-history` is the matter of shell, to record it, you must patch the shell (all shells on the system) with a feature that records every line of input (but if the user really wants to escape the logging, he can always find a way). That's because every application (not just a shell) can fork and execute any command it wishes. So the only foolproof way is to record every process it is started on your system (see the second link below). However, that still excludes everything that is done by the shell that doesn't require a new process to be spawned (all shell builtins) - someone could in principle call `echo "malicious command" | bash` and only `bash` will be visible as commandline. So both shell logging and exec logging is probably the way to go.

Relevant links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user
[User's executed commands log file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32740/users-executed-commands-log-file/32744#32744)

Answer (score 0):

You could use process accounting too.  Look for service psacct on Fedora and enable it.

Then you can see what user did/is doing by running things like:

```
sa  (list of all commands)
lastcomm bash  (who ran bash)
lastcomm vpathak   (what was run by vpathak)
```

This along with some shell history should give you a nice outline.

For better understanding of where logins come from and what keys are used, you can also view a detailed step wise intrusion attempt investigation at http://vpathak.tumblr.com/post/121343814158/fedora-audit-log-with-love-from-russia