# view history of opened programs Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, history

Is there a way to view a log, or history of all programs opened in Manjaro Linux?

Comment: Only if you started them from the terminal and haven't truncated your shell history...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `acct` package ([GNU accounting utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/accounting.html), which implements [BSD process accounting](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/security-accounting.html)). You'll get a log of all executed commands (not just interactive applications) which you can list with the [`lastcomm`](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/accounting.html#lastcomm) command.

Comment: Links broken.. I tested `acct` package and it doesn't seem as detailed as one would want.. example of missing info: Process ID which initiated the command, the file path of the process, its parent ID (if has any) etc. Problem is - if I want to query `/proc` with a process ID, then the process wouldn't necessarily be there... he could be gone until I try to query for it with more information.

Comment: @Dor If you want more logging, you have to request it explicitly. The right tool on Linux would be the audit subsystem, see for example [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25225/is-there-a-log-of-past-threads-that-are-now-closed/25229#25229). Unix systems run a lot of short-lived process, so if you log it all, you end up with a lot of information that isn't very useful (who cares what process ran `grep`?).

Comment: That is often true. But I'd expect it to be possible with an exclusions list (to exclude common binaries like `grep` etc.). Thank you!